# Does the ignition temperature of a substance decrease with the concentration of oxygen?

Tags: kinetics, combustion

Is it possible for a substance to undergo combustion at a temperature lower than its ignition point if the concentration of oxygen increases?

Comment: You asking a very general question for which there are likely to be exceptions. However, in general, if the oxygen concentration goes up (e.g. replacing an inert gas) then it would be easier to ignite the substance. The most notable exception is too much oxygen. Since ignition is a chain reaction, there has to be enough of the substance too.

Comment: i feel this question very interesting since i thought the same way. I also wish to test impact of air pressure on combustion if possible someday.